# Pandas loop over 2 dataframe and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files with some random numbers, as follow:

csv1.csv

```
0       906018
1       007559
2       910475
3       915104
4       600393
         ...  
5070    907525
5071    903079
5072    001910
5073    909735
5074    914861

length 5075
```

csv2.csv

```
0         5555
1         7859
2       501303
3       912414
4       913257
         ...  
7497    915031
7498    915030
7499    915033
7500    902060
7501    915038

length 7502
```

Some elements in `csv1` are present in `csv2` but I don't know exactly which one and I would like to extract those unique values. So my idea was to start merging together the 2 data frame, and than remove the duplicates.

so I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


unique_users = pd.read_csv('./csv1.csv')
unique_users['id']

identity = pd.read_csv('./csv2.csv')
identityNumber = identity['IDNumber']
identityNumber


df = pd.concat([identityNumber, unique_users])
```

Until here everything is perfect and the length of the df is the sum of the 2 length, but I realised the part where I got stuck.

the df concat it did its job and concat based on the index, so now I have tons of NaN.

and when I use the code:

```
final_result = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

The data frame does not drop any value because the df structure now look like this:

```
Identitynumber.    ID
5555               NaN
```

so I guess that drop duplicate is looking for the same exact values, but as they don't exist it just keeps it.

So what I would like to do, is loop over both data frame, and if a value in csv1 exists in csv2, I want them to be dropped.

Can anyone help with this please?

And please if you need more info just let me know.

UPDATE:

I think I found the reason why is not working but I am not sure how to solve this.

my csv1 looks like this:

```
id
906018,
007559,
910475,
915104,
600393,
007992,
502313,
004609,
910017,
007954,
006678,
```

in Jupiter notebook when I open the csv, it looks this way.

```
        id
906018  NaN
007559  NaN
910475  NaN
915104  NaN
600393  NaN
... ...
907525  NaN
903079  NaN
001910  NaN
909735  NaN
914861  NaN
```

and I do not understand why is seeing the id as NaN.

in fact I tried to add a new column into csv2, and as value I passed the id from csv1..and I can confirm that they are all `NaN`.
So I believe the source of the problem is surely this, which than reflects on all the other events.
Can anyone help to understand how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Do I understand correctly you want  to find values in df2 that already exist in df1, and remove them?  There are several similar (but distinct) operations, so clarity is important

Comment: @anon01 yes exactly, in df1 I have 5075 values, in df2 I have 7502. in df2 I have most of the values in df1..so if I drop the duplicate (7502 - 5075) I should have only the dinstinc

Comment: But now in my output I am having 9000 and plus as an output.which mean it did not dropped all the values duplicated

Comment: @NaydenVan it looks like it's being caused by the trailing commas. Since there's a comma at the end of each line, Pandas is expecting there to be two columns, and is assuming the numbers are the index. Remove the trailing commas and it should work, but it's hard to say for sure. Do both of your csv files look like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using ***`df.merge()`***:

```
# Data samples
data_1 = {'col_a': [906018,7559,910475,915104,600393,907525,903079,1910,909735,914861]}
data_2 = {'col_b': [5555,7859,914861,912414,913257,915031,1910,915104,7559,915038]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

# using isin() method
unique_vals = df1.merge(df2, right_on='col_b', left_on='col_a')['col_a']
new_df1 = df1[~df1.col_a.isin(unique_vals)]

# another approach
new_df1 = df1[df1.merge(df2, right_on='col_b', left_on='col_a', how='left')['col_b'].isna()]

print(new_df1)
#    col_a
# 0  906018
# 2  910475
# 4  600393
# 5  907525
# 6  903079
# 8  909735
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This approach worked. Can you please be so nice and explain me the process behind it please? I don't fully understand this bit ` right_on='col_b', left_on='col_a')['col_a']`

Comment: Sure, I’ll do it in an hour (I don’t have access to my laptop atm :)). In the meanwhile, do you mind to approve and upvote my answer if it workes?

Comment: So basically, you merge those dataframe on the targeted column of each one (`col_a of df1 and col_b of df2`). Then, you would have a merged dataframe in which column `col_a` of the merged dataframe contains all common values of df2 in it. Then, we use negation operator to exclude those values using the boolean indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the duplicates between your two dataframes and keep all the records in one dataframe df.

```
df = pandas.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This will still produce `NaN` if the column names of the two dataframes are different.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NaN` because when you concatenate, Pandas doesn't know what you want to do with the different column names of your two dataframes. One of your dataframes has an `IdentityNumber` column and the other has an `ID` column. Pandas can't figure out what you want, so it puts both columns into the resulting dataframe.

Try this:

```py
pd.concat([df1["IDNumber"], df2["ID"]]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this solution, and the final output length is 7502..a the beginning. a result I am expecting to have around 2400.

Comment: @NaydenVan see my edit. If all you want is to get the unique values of these two columns, use their column names directly in the concatenation.

Comment: I tried the edit swell and the result is always over 9000. :(

Comment: I just updated my post with, what I believe, is the source of the issue